# Who is/are "them"?

Tags: support, profile-page

Many user profiles now contain the following sentence:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.

So who is *them*? It seems this is a default sentence similar to *this page left intentionally blank*.  (My intake on John Carpenter movies has been rather low, recently).

Comment: A gender neutral `IT` by Stephen King could have sufficed I guess, e.g. "This profile has an air of mystery about It".

Comment: @StuartLC - didn't know profiles were sentient.

Comment: @Oded: they are plotting and scheming, and one day, they'll rise up and obliterate us all.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253463

Comment: @MartijnPieters - you mean: "a bunch of mindless moderators who'll be the first against the wall when the revolution comes"

Comment: I *told* you guys/gals that the Smeagol-grammar was somewhat confusing!

Answer (score 18):

It is a default placeholder text, it is shown when the *about me* field is left empty.

Here *them* is the gender neutral singular; e.g. it refers to the owner of the profile without specifying a gender like *him* or *her* would. See [*Singular they* on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they).

Comment: That's what _they_ want you to think. Notice how it's not a reflexive pronoun (_themselves_).

Comment: Or rather _themself_, since _they_ is singular here.

Comment: I heartily encourage you ask for *themself* as a feature request. :)

Comment: @JRichardSnape My feature request concerning that phrase is different: [I asked for it to be ditched](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251810/the-site-should-not-make-speculative-statements-about-its-users).